# Finite surjective morphism to normal affine variety is open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We have a finite surjective morphism  $\phi: X \to Y$ (it means that $k[X]$ is a finitely generated module over $\phi^*(k[Y])$), $Y$ is normal (it means that $k[Y]$ is normal). Why is it open in Zariski topology? (Image of open set is open?)

Comment: Please see this book: Algebraic Geometry I: Algebraic Curves, Algebraic Manifolds and Schemes, by V.I. Danilov，V.V. Shokurov, p220. It is a version of Zariski main theorem.

Answer (score 4):

Follows from the general fact that finite morphisms are closed. The basic idea here is that if $\phi: X = Spec(A)\rightarrow Spec(B)$ is a finite morphism, then if $J\leq B$ is an ideal of $B$, then $\phi(V(J)) = V(\phi^{\#-1}(J))$ where $\phi^\#: A\rightarrow B$ is the corresponding morphism of $\phi$.

Also, closed immersions given an example of finite morphisms that are not surjective.

**you have now changed the question from "closed" to "open" without mentioning this change...**

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to write that it should be open. Yes, finite morphism are always closed.

Comment: Sorry, i mixed it up

Comment: the 'open' case seems a little strange to me...do you have some non-trivial examples for schemes of dimension > 1? (note that open immersions are generally not finite...)

Comment: This task is in the paragraph before the paragraph about schemes. There has to be a simple solution

Comment: reference? (paragraph from where? and which section?)

Comment: I have this book only in Russian, "geometric introduction to algebraic geometry" written by Gorodentsev. This is the last proposition of paragraph 4

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems like we are asking ``when does continuous + finite + surjective  imply open?'' Perhaps if you drop the normality on the target hypothesis, then you can show normalization is not open, but I haven't checked this.